# Hide div when video starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

i am using the Youtube api to put a video on a background of a div, what i need is to detect when the video ends loading, i don't want to show the loading, before it ends loading i want to show a grey background, i already have the gray background set, but i can't detect when it really starts instead of the loading,

at the moment i have this on the javascript side:

```
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'kn-1D5z3-Cs',
            autoPlay: true,
            startAt: 10,
            loop: 1,
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'rel': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo': 0 },


            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.mute();
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
   if (event.data === 1) {

    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
```

in my html everything is fine, i just need to detect the start of the video and hide that background div, how to do that?

Comment: people may want to see your html code also. do you gave any id on this div? is it parent of video block or not?

Answer (score 0):

**i just need to detect the start of the video**

There is no `START` state for the Youtube video player. What you can use is the `event.data == 5` where 5 is the `video cued` state. That's because the video cued is the state when the video is about to start. You can now take advantage of this knowledge and hide your div when it's on video cue.

From the [Youtube Events docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events):

> "When a video is cued and ready to play, the player will broadcast a
> video cued (5) event."